# Creating two processes in Linux and getting output

Tags: python, linux, process, subprocess, output

I'm trying to run two processes in parallel. Both programs do not "end" without Ctrl+C (by the way, I'm on Linux), and so os.system will not return the output of a command. I want a way to create two processes independently of the main Python thread, and read text from them as it appears. I also want to be able to send characters to the process (not as a command, because the process interprets key presses by itself) I need something like this:

```
process1 = System("sh process1")
process2 = System("sh process2")

process1.Send("Hello, I'm sending text into process 1.")
text = process1.Read()

process2.Send(text)
```

Is there a way of doing this? I've looked into the Subprocess module, but I'm not sure it achieves quite what I want - or if it does, I'm not sure how to do it.

many thanks to anyone who answers,

Answer (score 2):

Subprocess does what you want. Here's an example of writing to and reading from an external command:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sed", "-u", "s/foo/bar/g"],
    shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

proc.stdin.write("foobar\n");
print proc.stdout.readline();  # Writes "barbar"
```

Comment: I have a problem. When trying to read a line, the program freezes. It should be outputting a Line. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: You can only read a line if the program outputs a line. Make sure it's outputting a full line, and that it's not buffering the output.